# SSL-Connection causes javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match (WSO2 Api Manager / Tomcat)

Tags: java, ssl, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am currently setting up a dockerized WSO Api Manager. We have got a wildcard certificates for our domain. I successfully transformed it into a java keystore and replaced the two jks files.

When I open the API manager, I get no ssl warnings and the browser marks my connection as secure.

When I try to login I get an error :

[image]

In the log files I get :

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-24 11:37:55,305]  INFO     
     {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} - Unable to sendViaPost   
     to    url[https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin]  
     {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: 
     <localhost> != </*.mydomain.io/mydomain.io/*.mydomain.io>
     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:341)
     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:277)
```

It looks like the Server is trying to do SSL connections to localhost. So how can I add a matching certificate to the keystore allowing localhost access?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `api-manager.xml` file , change all references of `localhost` to match your domain name , restart , and it should be good.

Setting

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
```

is a security risk , Hostname Verification is there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `axis2\axis2.xml` file on the `conf` folder you have to change the https `transportSender`to have the following line:

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
```

[Here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Enabling+SSL+Tunneling+through+a+Proxy+Server) you can read a little more about that