# API Gateway Admin Failure in WSO2 API Publisher 2.0.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently I integrated identity server 5.2.0 and API Manager 2.0.0 using key manager. Both of it run in same server.

I follow below guide to setup both of WSO2 Products. 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

Error happen when want to publish an API via Gateway Environment. It prompt an error message which is 
"Failed to Publish Environments
Production and Sandbox
Error while contacting the authentication admin services".

```
2017-04-25 17:51:17,225 [-] [localhost-startStop-1]  WARN QpidServiceComponent MQTT Transport is disabled as per configuration.
2017-04-25 17:52:23,505 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-43] ERROR APIGatewayManager Error occurred when publish to gateway Production and Sandbox
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while contacting the authentication admin services
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.AbstractAPIGatewayAdminClient.login(AbstractAPIGatewayAdminClient.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.AbstractAPIGatewayAdminClient.setup(AbstractAPIGatewayAdminClient.java:50)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.<init>(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:37)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.publishToGateway(APIGatewayManager.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.publishToGateway(APIProviderImpl.java:1481)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways(APIProviderImpl.java:1292)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:36)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:136)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:712)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:450)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:338)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1952)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3640)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_13(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:47)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: hostname in certificate didn't match: <localhost> != </eae.resolvtech.net>
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.AuthenticationAdminStub.login(AuthenticationAdminStub.java:659)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.AbstractAPIGatewayAdminClient.login(AbstractAPIGatewayAdminClient.java:87)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <localhost> != </eae.resolvtech.net>
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:341)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:277)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:260)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:659)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:195)
    ... 96 more
2017-04-25 17:52:24,284 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-43] ERROR APIExecutor Failed to publish service gateway while executing APIExecutor. 
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.FaultGatewaysException
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPIforStateChange(APIProviderImpl.java:1403)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.updateAPIforStateChange(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:36)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:712)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:450)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:338)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1952)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3640)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_13(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:47)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-04-25 17:52:24,290 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-43] ERROR DefaultLifeCycle org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while contacting the authentication admin services"},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
2017-04-25 17:52:24,294 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-43] ERROR GovernanceArtifactImpl Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed. Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while contacting the authentication admin services"},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while contacting the authentication admin services"},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:482)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:338)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1952)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3640)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_13(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:47)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there any configure issue that I missed?

Comment: This is already answered in here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43043075/1008424

Comment: I already setup the HostnameVerifier parameter.. still have this issues..

Answer (score 0):

I've already had the exact same problem. The cause was the incorrect change of the admin user password. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Maintaining+Logins+and+Passwords)

Comment: I've already manage to configure this part. But then still have this problem. Is anything else that need to be configure?

Comment: Whenever I face odd errors in the API Manager, usually I start with a clean installation and apply my configurations to try to identify the point where a specific error shows up. API Manager does not require a lot of configurations that makes this process infeasible. In my opinion, to do this is less time consuming.

About the problem you are tackling, it may be the case of a deleted role which is used by any API scopes. It happened with me once.

Comment: Same as me, I start clean installation and try to apply my old configuration. But when want to integrate Identity Server and API Manager it will come with the same error. 
May I know, is there any other way to integrate IS and API Manager in same server? 
May I know if you have other suggestion that could help in this case?

Comment: Well... I'd check the ports. You certainly already have configured the ports offset, but double check the specific server ports in the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products#DefaultPortsofWSO2Products-Product-specificports).
Have you tested the setup using two different servers?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I already setup and tested two different server and still this problem happen.